Executives are pressing me to take over another managers team
I am relatively new to this company I currently manage a team of cloud engineers.
The manager of the managed services team left due to a dispute over team compensation.
I have managed a global team of engineers and managed services in the past. Myself, the manager that resigned an another team all report to the same director.
The Sr. Director, Sr. VP and COO all are calling me directly to get me to take this role. But asking me not to tell my immediate director.
My immediate director has asked if I'd be interested in a lateral and give up the current team of engineers and take the managed services team.
There are red flags and while I like the idea of the challenge the idea of politics are concerning.
I'm having a conversation with a mentor but I guess I'm looking for another opinion. It is more work and staff and if I do take it I'd like a bump in title Sr. Manager and additional compensation.
Thank you for any suggestions

VTC as we cannot tell you what choice to make, and that's the closest thing to a question I could find.

Personally, I would refuse. But if you're really enticed by the bump in promotion, you can always try to contact the person you'd be replacing. You could just tell them "Some people want me to take over the position you just left. Could I have a short talk with you about it. Please don't tell anyone I've contacted you. I don't want to create any unnecessary drama."


But asking me not to tell my immediate director.

That's a huge red flag. I would go back to the Sr. Director, Sr. VP and COO and ask them straight up "why?". If they can't come up with a reasonable explanation I would proceed very carefully.
Chances are they want to throw your current boss under the bus. If that's the case they will also do it with you when there is an opportune moment. If you feel your current boss is doing a good job and there is no reason to axe them, I would probably walk away.

I wouldn't it consider a red flag - YET. The reason is they are likely considering you as a shortlist candidate for the job. There is no value in bringing it to your current direct report until you say yes or otherwise express interest.
If you aren't interested, then there is nothing to have discussed with your boss. If you are interested, then they, not you will bring it to your boss.
Likely there is nothing evil going on here. They are just keeping their options close to the vest until they have a candidate.
Now the reason I said "Yet" on red flags. You mentioned why the previous manager left. If they wanted more money and didn't get it, that is one thing. If they were promised more and didn't get it, that would be a red flag.
